# Enter to submit in chrome app

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome-app, enter

I created a little app, that should perform an action when enter pressed. When I open the html in a browser, it works like I want it to, but when I open it as a chrome app it doesn't. Here's the html:

```
<input type="text" id='command' onkeydown="keyDown()">
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
function keyDown() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var command = document.getElementById('command');
        var value = command.value;
        if (value === "exit") {
            alert('hi');
            var mainWindow = chrome.app.window.get('firstInstall');
            mainWindow.close();
        } else {
            document.getElementyId('wrong').className = 'unhidden';
        }
    }
}
```

(don't mind the 'else{...}' part)

In the browser, the code alerts 'hi', like it should. That's how I know it works in the browser. The chrome app doesn't work though.
Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Your `id='command` is never closed. just add `'` at the end of command in your html

Comment: Sorry about that, it actually is closed. Something went wrong copying the code to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that your HTML actually has the closing quote on the ID attribute, like

```
<input type="text" id='command' onkeydown="keyDown()">
```

(If not, then that will cause other problems for you)

The real issue, though, is that Chrome Apps don't allow JavaScript text in HTML files. This applies both to inline scripts and to event attributes like `onkeydown`, and is part of the security measures that Chrome Apps implement to ensure that your app is not executing untrusted JavaScript.

The way to fix this is to have a piece of JavaScript that attaches an event listener to the `<input>` tag, like this:

```
document.getElementById('command').addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
```

That will attach the `keyDown()` function as a listener to the `onkeydown` event on the element with the id `command`.

You can read more about `addEventListener` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

And more about the content security policy that Chrome Apps enforce is here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy

Answer (score -2):

At keyDown function, define event object (keyword) as below :

```
<input type="text" id='command' onkeydown="keyDown(event)">
```

Through which, event object will be accessible as local variable in function :

```
function keyDown(event){ 
    if(event.keyCode == 13) { 
        var command =  document.getElementById('command'); 
        var value = command.value; 
        if(value === "exit"){ 
            alert('hi'); 
            var mainWindow = chrome.app.window.get('firstInstall'); 
            mainWindow.close();
        } else { 
            document.getElementById('command').className = 'unhidden'; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read the other answer to understand why yours is incorrect.

Comment: Not to mention that it does not even attempt to deal with the problem of handler not running. Or makes any sense at all, to be honest: `event` is undefined in the context of inline code in `onkeydown`.